# How to adjust the labels on ggplot2 line graph to show the group, and add space

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following data table:

```
gIN <- c("A_1","A_2","A_3","A_4","B_1","B_2","B_3","B_4","B_5","C_1","C_2","C_3")
bc <- c(1219.79, 1486.84, 1255.80, 941.87, 588.19, 304.02, 279.71, 373.40, 179.89, 385.02, 218.76, 423.33)
group <- c("A","A","A","A","B","B","B","B","B","C","C","C")

ex <- data.frame("gIN" = gIN, "bc" = bc, "group" = group)
```

I have two issues:

(A) I would like the x-axis labels to read the value for "group", not for "gIN'.  Also,

(B) I would like to increase the spacing between adjacent groups.  A, B, and C are too close together so this will make larger graphs difficult on the eye.

The line is here:

```
ggplot(data=ex, aes(x=gIN, y=bc, group=group)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point() + 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1))
```

Produces this plot:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

user4968354 suggested I look into facet, and I came up with this.  Pretty much what I was looking for:

```
ggplot(data=ex) + geom_line(aes(x=gIN, y=bc,group=group)) + geom_point(aes(x=gIN, y=bc)) + facet_grid(. ~group, scales="free")
```

Cheers.